# how to order a laravel query by 2 elements and give 1 priority laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a model called `notes` and i want to sort them by `created_at` and take 10 of them and among those 10 i want to show the ones who have the higher `order` which is a field on model . now what i have done is like below :

```
        $notes = Note::take(10)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->orderBy('order','desc')->get();
```

now i want to give priority to `order` than `created_at` field. but it seems not to work now . any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Eloquent returns a collection you can use the built in methods.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

```
$notes = Note::take(10)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->sortByDesc('order');
```

Also depending on what version of Laravel you are using you can use

```
Note::latest()->take(10)->get()->sortByDesc('order');
```

Comment: i have an othre model with uses pagination that i want to sort too .

Comment: @Farshad no pagination won't work right from the collection, well it can, but you would be using the pagination PHP class and not right off your query, i'm not 100% as I'm on my mobile right now but you should be able to use the `->reorder('order')` method before get. I've never used this however.